# antlr4: get index of next (optional) token

Tags: antlr, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I have language with optional clauses (`CL1`, `CL2`).

grammar rule:
`func : FUNC ID "(" (CL1 (ID | CL11 ID))? ")" (CL2 (ID | CL21 ID))? EOS ;`

Because of optionality, I can't even use `getChild(i).getText()` since "i" becomes non-deterministic.

While running code generation, I need to pick `ID` after `CL1` or `CL2`.
If I do not have index of `CL1`, I haven't got one for `ID`, that follows it.

`function fnFoo () meni attrBar ;`
will have different token positions compared to
`function fnFoo (arg pBar) meni attrBar ;`

I used another approach of:
a. first detecting if token of this type exists `ctx.getTokens(LangParser.CL1)[0]` or `ctx.CL1()`
b. picking its tokenIndex `ctx.CL1().getSymbol().tokenIndex`
c. advancing `tokenIndex + 1` to next locate `ID`

But at this point, I realize, that this `tokenIndex` is not the same index used in `getChild(i)` API.
And there is no API to pick token text, using `tokenIndex` to begin with.

How would one handle this situation?

ps: I use nodejs runtime with visitors, using ANTLR 4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
func
 : FUNC ID '(' cl1? ')' cl2? EOS 
 ;

cl1
 : CL1 CL11? ID
 ;

cl2
 : CL2 CL21? ID
 ;
```

In the `funcContext` you can then do:

```js
if (ctx.cl1()) {
   // cl1 is present
   // do something with ctx.cl1().CL1() and/or ctx.cl1().ID()
}
```

Comment: thanks @bart-kiers - coincidentally, this is exactly what I ended u trying just now. It works. Given you as well suggest the same, I take that this is the only approach pattern to handle the situation.

Comment: out of curiosity, wouldn't "return/print token text, IF it exists" be a very obvious API to expect in ANTLR? Or my use is deviating from what original authors intended?

Comment: Would be more of a language feature., I guess. Like the `?.` operator for optional property accesses in TypeScript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing Other languages, like Ruby and C# have similar operators.